# Laravel page expired 419 on hosting with localhost working

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to host my website on an online hosting, I've already done this many times before.
But this time I'm getting an 419 page expired error, and I don't know what it's really about, I'm using the database session driver, and I'm using the csrf field everytime on this forms. Note that ajax forms are working normally, but post forms are not working. (I've also cleared cache many times and everything)

Here is my .env File :

`APP_NAME=Laravel

APP_ENV=local

APP_KEY=base64:UQ/XKTRaoI8xxvSMbyiPtQRftArL8CyXzNW0Lu4+6RI=

APP_DEBUG=true

APP_URL=XXXXX

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=XXXXX

DB_USERNAME=XXXXX

DB_PASSWORD=XXXXX

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log

CACHE_DRIVER=file

QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

SESSION_DRIVER=database

SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=http://promocups.eu/new

REDIS_PASSWORD=null

REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXXX

MAIL_PASSWORD="XXXXX"

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null

MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=

PUSHER_APP_KEY=

PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"

MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

MOLLIE_KEY=XXXXXXXX`

> Here is an example of a form :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                      @csrf
                        <input class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                        @error('name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror

                        <input class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
                        @error('email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror

                        <input id="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror

                        <input id="password-confirm" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required>


                        <div class="form-button">
                            <button id="submit" type="submit" class="ibtn">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

> Could it also be a mariaDB problem, because the db on the host is mariadb and I was working on mysql on local host and I didn't change anything about the config.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Before pull your project on development server,  clear everyting, such as `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan view:clear` here you get this error may be, for the cache of your session. Which is generated on your local machine.

Comment: @sta, Yes I did clear everything on the server, and it did not work :/